# A solution to the issue of saving EF associated author to book table

Tags: c#

I am developing a library project. I am using MVVM pattern in my project. When I try to associate the author named "Author1", whose ID value is 1 in the database on the ViewModel side, with the new book, I get the error as follows. I couldn't figure it out. Where could there be a mistake at this point?
Note: Values are coming to the NewBook object from the view side and there is no problem with data binding.
I ask for your help.

> Error: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.'
> SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

```
using (var Db= new LibraryDataContext())
{
var author = Db.Authors.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Name == "Author1");
NewBook.AuthorOf = author;
Db.Books.Add(NewBook);
Db.SaveChanges();
}

public class Book 
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public int AssetNumber { get; set; }

public string Barcode { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public int AuthorId { get; set; }

public Yazar AuthorOf { get; set; }

public string? ISBN { get; set; }

public int PublisherId { get; set; }

public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }

public string? PrintDate { get; set; }

public string? NumberOffPrint { get; set; }

public string? NumberOfPages { get; set; }

public string? Language { get; set; }

public string? Translator { get; set; }

public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

public bool Active { get; set; }
}
}

public class Author
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

public bool Active { get; set; }
}
}

public class LibraryDataContext : DbContext
{
public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Reader> Readers { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
public virtualDbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
string connectionString = @"Data Source=Data\Database.db;";

optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
using (var Db= new LibraryDataContext()) {
  var author = Db.Authors.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Name == "Author1");
  NewBook.AuthorId = author?.Id; // Id --> AuthorId
  Db.Books.Add(NewBook);
  Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

P. S. `author` is a record while tables are linked each other using basic types, int as the most frequent. In the `Author` class, `Id` is the primary key which serves as a unique record identifier. And `Book` refers `Author` using its `Id` stored in `Book.AuthorId`.

Comment: Hello
Why doesn't it work when we give the author object directly instead of AuthorId?
I have seen such uses in some examples.
Thanks.

Comment: If the answer helped you please accept it. Then I'll provide you further explanations.

Comment: Hello
By the way, it is written in the codes. But I am using SQLite as database. Could it be related to this?
I would appreciate it if you could share information.

Comment: It's not related either SQLite or any database control system. It's a common technology. I put the post scriptum with explanation. I guess you are little bit confused with examples you've learned.

Comment: Hello
Thank you for the explanation. So, isn't it possible to do it via object? Because I check the existence of the author with a method and act accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible using the hole object (or record) to assign it to a field in any table.

Comment: Just use any DB browser and look at the table's contents. Pay attention at `Book.AuthorId`.

Comment: Well, the method returns an Author object. Will I use the Id information of the value returned from the method to use the existing or absent author?
Is the ID information of the newly added author visible in the object after it is registered?
Do you have any suggestions for a different approach?
Thanks.

Comment: "Db.Authors.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Name == "Author1")" returns the Author object where `Name' is 'Author1'. The Id in this object is the unique (in the scope of Author's table) Id which is behalf of this object only. Other Authors objects have their own Ids.

Comment: Of cause Id is visible, you can alwasy read it. Typically such ids are generated by DBCS. When you create a new Author, you don't need to assign it the Id yourself. You need to save the new record first then you can read its Id.

Comment: Hello
I made a few tries last night.
var author = Db.Authors.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Name == "Author1");
NewBook.AuthorOf = author;
When I use it like this, it associates the author of the book. The problem I'm having is caused by accessing data through different DataContext. I did this this way to separate the data layer and ViewModel layer. I created a DataAccess class. Here I obtain some data with EF methods. I think I'm using it incorrectly. Do you have any suggestions for me on this matter?

Comment: Please create a new question and provide all details, including code exempts.